# C++: Reading a json object from file with nlohmann json

Tags: c++, json, file, nlohmann-json

I am using the nlohmann's json library to work with json objects in c++. Ultimately, I'd like to read a json object from a file, e.g. a simple object like this.

```
{
"happy": true,
"pi": 3.141
}
```

I'm not quite sure how to approach this. At https://github.com/nlohmann several ways are given to deserialise from a string literal, however it doesn't seem trivial to extend this to read in a file. Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

#### Update 2017-07-03 for [*JSON for Modern C++ version 3*](http://nlohmann.github.io/json/)

Since *version 3.0*, `json::json(std::ifstream&)` is deprecated. One should use [`json::parse()`](http://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a265a473e939184aa42655c9ccdf34e58.html#a265a473e939184aa42655c9ccdf34e58) instead:

```
std::ifstream ifs("test.json");
json jf = json::parse(ifs);

std::string str(R"({"json": "beta"})");
json js = json::parse(str);
```

For more basic information on how to use nlohmann's json library, see [nlohmann FAQ](http://nlohmann.github.io/json/home/faq/).

---

#### Update for *JSON for Modern C++ version 2*

Since *version 2.0*, [`json::operator>>() id deprecated`](http://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a9e06deabe69262c3ffc5533d32856983.html#a9e06deabe69262c3ffc5533d32856983). One should use `json::json()` instead:

```
std::istringstream ifs("{\"json\": true}");
json j(ifs);
```

---

#### Original answer for *JSON for Modern C++ version 1*

Use `json::operator>>(std::istream&)`:

```
json j;
std::stringstream ifs("{\"json\": true}");
ifs >> j;
```

Comment: Hi there, for version 2.0.0, I added a constructor to cope with an input stream directly, so you could write `json j(ifs);`. See http://nlohmann.github.io/json/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a9857835334d38ba04959e348ca6be208.html#a9857835334d38ba04959e348ca6be208 for more details.

Comment: Do you have to close the ifstream to prevent memory leaks?

Comment: @IntegrateThis No - the `ifstream` closes the stream when it goes out of scope. Manually closing `*fstream`s is rarely done. Only if you want to `close` and then `open` something else using the same `*fstream`.

Comment: What about enabling exception handling on the `std::ifstream` to figure out if the file was successfully opened and read?

Comment: @YSC: It would be better to enable exceptions to catch errors regarding loading from the file I suppose, right?

Comment: This is far (faaar) beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 14):

The constructor `json j(ifs)` is deprecated and will be removed in version 3.0.0. Since version 2.0.3 you should write:

```
std::ifstream ifs("test.json");
json j = json::parse(ifs);
```